# Find $f(3)$ if $f(f(x))=x^{2}+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Let $a,b,f(x),x$ be positive integers such that If $a>b$ then $f(a)>f(b)$ and $f(f(x))=x^{2}+2$ . Find $f(3)$

My approach:

Replacing $x$ with $f(x)$ in the equation gives $f(f(f(x))) = f(x)^2 + 2$, but $f(f(x)) = x^2 + 2$ so $$f(x^2+2) = f(x)^2 + 2$$
how do i proceed after this. Please help. Thanks alot!

Comment: Since $f$ is increasing set $f(1)=a$ then $f(a)=3$ there are only $1,2$ values below. can you infer some upper bound for $a$ ?

Comment: @zwim could you please elaborate. I know i somehow have to use $f(a)>f(b) $ if $a>b$ but i am unable to see how to use it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the problem is poorly written.  One of the premises is that if $x \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, then $f(x) \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$  This premise is not *obvious* from the problem's presentation - i.e. the statement "let ... $f(x), x$, be positive integers".

Comment: I'm not seeing how you made the observation $f(x^2+2)=(f(x))^2+2$....

Comment: @user2661923 , i also thought the same. But this is how the problem was stated in the original source.

Comment: The answer of lulu is conclusive.  Another way of summarizing the answer of lulu is that $f(1)$ must be a positive integer, $f(1)$ must be $> 1$, and $f(1)$ must be $< 3$.

Comment: @Mike, since $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)^{2}+2$ but $f(f(x))=x^{2}+2$ so $f(x^{2}+2)=f(x)^{2}+2$

Comment: Yes you are right. My mistake!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Here's a simplified example to illustrate what I'm saying. Consider the function where $ f(a) = a$ for rationals and  $f(a) = 0 $ for irrationals. Since $f(f(a) ) = f(a) $ (check that this is true for a rational or irrational), can we do the substitution of $x = f(a) $ to conclude that $f(x) = x$ for all $x$ in the domain? Clearly no because it's not true for irrationals. We can only conclude that is true for if there is an $a$ such that $ x = f(a) $. The restriction is that $x$ needs to be in the range. (Also, avoid notation doing double duty.)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah, I see where you're coming from. I misinterpreted what OP did.

Comment: @Ggsvdgdhddh I've re-written some of the question for clarity by removing the use of $=$ as an assignment operator (in the sense of programming languages).  It's still not quite how I'd put it; rather I've pulled some of your comment into it.  If you wish to rephrase it, feel free, but try to avoid the concept of the substitution "$x = f(x)$" since when interpreted as an equation it's necessarily false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $f(f(1))=3$ so there is some natural number $n$ such that $f(n)=3$.

If $f(1)>3$ then there could be no solution to $f(n)=3$ so we must have $f(1)\in \{1,2,3\}$.

If $f(1)=3$ then we have $3=f(f(1))=f(3)$, a contradiction.

If $f(1)=1$ then we would have $3=f(f(1))=f(1)$, a contradiction.

Thus $f(1)=2$.

It follows that $$f(2)=f(f(1))=1^2+2=3$$ from which we deduce that $$f(3)=f(f(2))=2^2+2=6$$ and we are done.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Good point.  Let me see if I can repair that...

Comment: @CalvinLin  I've rewritten to avoid that substitution.  Thanks for pointing out the gap.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Another gap should be observed as well...All we've done with this sort of reasoning is to show what the value must be *assuming $f(x)$ exists*.   I assume that this is what the OP intended, and I didn't think about constructing an actual solution to the functional equation.

Comment: BrianMoehring pointed out that the substitution is actually valid. I misunderstood what OP did (in part because the details weren't listed out).

Answer (score 4):

Note that $f$ is by definition strictly monotonic. So consider: If $f(3)<3$ then we can only have $f(3)=1$ or $f(3)=2$. Else if $f(3)=3$ we have $f(3)=f(f(3)) = 3^2+2=11$, so this cannot be. Finally if $f(3)>3$ we have $f(3) < f(f(3))=11$.

$f(3)=1,2$ would imply $f(1)=f(f(3)) = 11>f(3)$.

Generally we get that $f(x)$ cannot be $x$, else $x=x^2+2$. Also $f(f(1)) = 3$, $f(f(2)) = 6$, $f(f(3)) = 11$. But as $f(3)>3$ (and $f(x)>3$ for $x>3$) this means $f(2)=3$.

But then $f(3) = f(f(2)) = 6$. Thus we’re done.

Comment: Thank you so muchhhh!!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Could be? You appear to know better, so it’s probably that way.

Comment: I've been surprised about regional uses of words before (e.g. "positive"), so I tend not to assume.

Comment: @BrianMoehring My problem here is that I’m not a native english speaker, so I’m not used to using each possible term in english. In german we just say *monoton*.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: What surprising meaning of "positive" have you encountered?

Comment: @BrianTung I believe that in French, positive means non-negative, EG 0 is both positive and negative. I stand with Moehring on this "regional uses of words".

Comment: @CalvinLin: I did not mean to suggest that I disbelieved in it; I was merely curious as to the specific case of "positive."